# Unable to load plugin watch (less)

Tags: css, less, watch

Estou tentando instalar o less no meu windows, quando dou um

```
lessc --watch agency.less custom.css
```

Aparece:

> Unable to load plugin watch please make sure that it is installed
> under or at the same level as less

esse `custom.css` seria meu arquivo css?
Obrigada!

Comment: Melhor editar o título de sua pergunta com uma frase em Português, fiz uma edição para que você não tenha  votos negativos

Comment: A mensagem de erro está informando que o plugin watch deve ser instalado no mesmo nível que o less, por isso não o encontra, ela não cita o arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está tentando instalar e sim executar o less com o comando lessc.

1. Use o Node Version Manager (nvm) para instalar e usar a versão mais recente do Node.js - **caso** não tenha o node instalado em seu Windows, siga os passos para instalar o nvm no [doc oficial](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

1.2. Instale o node

`nvm install latest`

2. Execute o instalador de less com o npm, navegue até a pasta do projeto e digite:

```
npm install less -g
npm i menos --save-dev
```

3. Somente após instalado o less execute o comando de compilação lessc, por exemplo

`lessc caminho-origem/index.less caminho-destino/index.css`